# Regex to separate digits with spaces only if there are more than two digits

Tags: c#, regex

I have a number of string that contain a mix of alphanumeric characters, for example:

```
10
1234
123-t123b-+1
ff 8765 12
```

I want to separate the digits by a space, but only if there are three or more digits next to each other.  So the above examples would become:

```
10
1_2_3_4
1_2_3-t1_2_3b-+1
ff 8_7_6_5 12
```

(added spaces shown with underscored for clarity).  Is there a regex that can handle this or do I need to do this programatically?

Comment: Is regex a hard requirement? I don't think regex a good fit for this problem. Matching the digits should be easy, but interspersing characters in a matched substring isn't, at least I don't think it is.

Comment: Not a hard requirement, more curious as to if a regex can do this.

Comment: This is classic positioning problem in regex. Solution is going to be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need something like this:

```
var text = "10" + Environment.NewLine + 
           "1234" + Environment.NewLine + 
           "123-t123b-+1" + Environment.NewLine + 
           "ff 8765 12";

var regex = new Regex(@"\d{3,}");
var replacedText = regex.Replace(text, match => string.Join<char>(" ", match.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not a pure regex but it does the job, which is the main thing.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if C# supports `\G` but try this pattern

```
\B(?=\d{2})|(?<!^)\G(?=\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW8qM8/2)

---

here is my second pattern without using `\G`

```
(?<=\d)(?=\d\d)|(?<=\d\d)(?=\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW8qM8/3)
explanation:

```
(?<=\d)(?=\d\d)     # 0-width after 1 digit and before 2 digits ie 1^234 or 12^34  
|                   # or  
(?<=\d\d)(?=\d)     # 0-width after 2 digits and before 1 digit ie 12^34 or 123^4
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately in c# it doesn't quite do the job as it leaves the last two digits together (e.g. 1234 becomes 1 2 34).

Comment: @alphabravo Your 2nd demo works. Care to explain the regex ?

Comment: @alphabravo: You solved the problem my solution was lacking.

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this

match any number followed by two numbers, the second number has to be followed by at least one number and any number digits after that

UPDATE: my pattern can be shortened to: `(\d(?=\d{2})\d+)`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string pattern = @"(\d(?=\d{2})\d(?=\d)\d+)";
        string content = "10" + Environment.NewLine +
                         "1234" + Environment.NewLine +
                         "123 - t123b - +1" + Environment.NewLine +
                         "ff 8765 12";

        var reg = new Regex(pattern);
        var replacedText = reg.Replace(content, match => string.Join<char>(" ", match.Value));

        Console.WriteLine(replacedText);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure regex so far I have been successful in finding position and replacing with a `space` except when last digit is followed by a `whitespace`. Here is my solution which is close but up to the mark. If you wish to **downvote** then do provide some advice in direction of solution.

**Regex #1**: `(?<=\d)(?=(\d)(?=\d|.))`

**Explanation**: It places the *regex pointer* by finding a position ( *zero width* ) preceded by a digit and followed by a digit. **Latter digit**( *right one*) should be followed by a digit or anything other than `whitespaces`.

<kbd>[Regex101 Demo#1](https://regex101.com/r/fD6sM9/1)</kbd>

---

**Regex #2**: `(?<=\d)(?=(\d|\w)(?=\d|.))`

**Explanation**: This one has a little variation. It places the *regex pointer* by finding a position ( *zero width* ) preceded by a digit and followed by a digit or anything other than `whitespaces`.

<kbd>[Regex101 Demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/fD6sM9/2)</kbd>

Now the only problem left is matching the `whitespaces` followed by a valid case.